# Magento2 Migration tool integrity check failed

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am getting the following error when running the data migration tool on a existing Magento 1.9.2.2 data base. I have configured the tool to exclude the custom tables. What could I be missing?

I get the following error

```
[Migration\Exception]   Integrity Check failed
```

Even though all integrity check done 100%

[image]

Comment: I also encountered the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That is strange. Integrity check should show the tables or fields that are missing. You can write try-catch with trace message in \Migration\Mode\Data::runIntegrity to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
-vvv switch to give you more information
```